# How to serialize methods and parameters like WSDL auto generated class in c#

Tags: c#, serialization, soap, wsdl

Hello here a webmethod auto generated by wsdl.exe

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/GetTitles", RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
public TitleS[] GetTitles(int[] ids) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("GetTitles", new object[] {
                ids});
    return ((TitleS[])(results[0]));
}
```

I would like to get the soap xml or just Soap body xml of this calling method and never call the Invoke method.
The result I would like to get is that  :

```
<soap:Body>
<GetTitles xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <ids>
    <id>1</id>
  </ids>
</GetTitles>
```

How can have this result, is it possible to have a simple method to build soap body from a method and it's parameters because I have lot of Webmethods

Thanks!

Comment: Have you Taken a Look at the SoapEnvelope Class in the Microsoft.Web.Services3 NameSpace.  There is a load method off that class in which to load the Soap Message into the class and then there is a property called Body which will return you a XmlElement Type of the Body of the soap Message.

Comment: Hello, is this class is compatible with mono 2.0? I dont found it

Comment: By this link its not http://www.mono-project.com/archived/wse/ ,  turns out the WSE is much older than I first thought I didn't see mention of mono so no this is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally never used it, but [SOAP UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoapUI) seems like a good fit for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reesponse, but I need to achieve this with only .Net Framework because it's for a unity3D project running on IOS :)

Comment: Does it have any restriction with using .Invoke? The only other alternative I can think of is using Reflection (apart from of course replicating what wsdl.exe itself does).

Comment: The .Invoke method send the soap message with an httprequest object I want to send the soap with a networkstream. IOS doesn t support to send/receive soap by http. I never realy use reflection it's time for me to learn :). I'll continue..